# Don't existing service providers already do this?

Tags: us20130318182

The patent as described at http://www.google.com/patents/US20130318182 seems to describe a service already offered by Foursquare, and probably by Facebook and Google.

It claims to cover a server sending messages to mobile devices based on their geo-location.

So are FS/FB/etc. in breach? What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/patents/US20130318182 is an "Application" -- that is the patent has not been granted (yet).

The priority date is "May 25, 2012" so any implementation which provides exactly claimed would be in violation of the patent was it ever granted if such service were started after that date, but would be fine and possibly invalidate the patent if such service were started before that date.